# CUDA 2D, 3D thread blocks

Tags: cuda

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA, 
Maximum x- or y-dimension of a block 1024
Maximum z-dimension of a block 64

Does it mean we can have 1024 x 1024 x 64 threads per block or we can have a maximum of 1024+64 threads in a block?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limits are defined in Append G of recent programming guides, but the answer is either 512 or 1024 threads per block **total**, depending on whether you have a Fermi, or older card.

So for Fermi

```
blockDim.x * blockDim.y * blockDim.z <= 1024
```

and for GT200/G90/G80/Ion:

```
blockDim.x * blockDim.y * blockDim.z <= 512
```

Note the are other resource limits (shared memory and  registers) which may require block sizes to be be smaller than the limits, depending on code complexity. This is also discussed at some length in the programming guide.

Comment: I think the confusion is that in the manual it says the "maximum dimension" meaning the *maximum value of that parameter* but within the limits of how many threads per block are possible.